# can I have a real time threat protection on azure app services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have azure app service where I am running a tomcat application, is there a way / or any in-build anti-malware option is available if not how to implement threat protection in this app service

Comment: Have you tried googling "threat protection azure app service"?

Comment: Yes I have tried but not getting anything with app service all I am getting is cloud service and vm

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service uses the same Antimalware solution used by Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines but it is completely managed by our Engineering team on regular basis.

Also as a PAAS service we currently donot provide anti-malware scanning as a customer facing service.  The implementation of A/V on our service has gone through, and will continue to go through, changes as we tune it for its primary purpose.  Its primary purpose is to protect the service itself (PAAS) from viruses.

If you have custom requirement of having providing anti-virus scanning then IaaS VMs should be the choice as they have installable extension for virus scanning and the choice of different A/V technologies.

You can check the documentation in the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-antimalware Screen shot of the information under Architecture section of the link.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-security-readme

Answer (score -1):

For now, there is no native virus scanning / anti-malware feature on Websites. However you could implement it with third party API like [ClamAV](https://github.com/tekmaven/nClam) or the extension in Azure App Service named with `Tinfoil Security`.

There are two ways to integrate `Tinfoil Security` to you app and this is the [introduction](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/azure), first you could refer to this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/web-vulnerability-scanning-for-azure-app-service-powered-by-tinfoil-security/) ,I tried this way however It show `Failed to purchase`. So maybe you could try another way. Under Development Tools in your App choose `Extensions` , click Add button then Choose Extension, on the list there is a `Tinfoil Security` , that's what we need. I tried this way, it could be integrated to my App.

Comment: This is paid service?

Comment: @Raju, the both ways are not charged.

Comment: @Raju, if you choose to use the Tinfoil Security( Security Scanning under the Diagnose and Solve Problems), it will be charged.